# R fill in data value based on data range and variable combinations

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames which have been merged together, 1. with fine scale GPS position data along with datetimes and a site id; and 2. observations from each site inlcluding site id, individual id, and when the monitoring began and ended at a given site. In the merged data frame some of the individual id values are NA because the two tables didn't match on the date times and site id. However, I want to fill in individual id where the site ids match and the date time is between the start and end dates associated with that monitoring event. All these fields are available one table. I am currently using a loop to fill in the missing individual ids, but I have millions of rows and it's very inefficient. Any suggestions for improved efficieincy?

MWE

```
library(tidyverse)
dates = seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/05/01'), by="day")

df1 = data.frame(site = rep(1:2,each = 5), 
                 date_time = c(dates[1:5], dates[10:14]),
                 lat = rnorm(10,0,20), 
                 lon=rnorm(10,150,180))

df2 = data.frame(site = c(1,2), id = c('A','B'), 
                 start = c(dates[1], dates[10]),
                 date_time = c(dates[2], dates[11]),
                 end=c(dates[5], dates[14]) )

dat = merge(df1,df2,all=T)
```

For loop used to solve this problem (inefficiently)

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  tmp = dat[i,]
  if(!is.na(dat[i,'id'])){next}
  dat[i,'id'] = df2 %>% filter(site==tmp$site, start<=tmp$date_time, end>=tmp$date_time) %>% pull(id)
}
```

Comment: Would you be happy to use *data.table*? If so, you can do non-equi joins like `df2[df1, on=c("site","start<=date_time","end>=date_time")]`

Comment: @thelatemail this might work. Thank you for the suggestion. I'm having some errors pop up - suggesting a bad merge (duplicates) - so I'm working to see if that can be resolved.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer, but also consider: `library(data.table); setDT(df1); setDT(df2); df1[df2, on=c("site","date_time>=start","date_time<=end"), c("start","end") := .(i.start,i.end)]` which seems to do what you want to add stuff to `df1`

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, I think this or use of foverlap may solve the problem. Thanks again for your thoughts - it's helping me down the right path :)

Comment: @thelatemail your first solution worked. I had some duplicates in the id table I was trying to match to, which gave an error, but now it is working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @thelatemail this solution worked:

```
df2[df1, on=c("site","start<=date_time","end>=date_time")]
```